# Symfony2: No route found /demo/contactus

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to symfony and following the AcmeDemo i created a new page for Contact Us. At the moment it is working for the url localhost:8000/contactus but following the same implementation of demo/secured/login it should be localhost:8000/demo/contactus which gives 404.

I am not sure what wrong i am doing.

**routing.yml**

```
_demo_contactus:
 resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/ContactusController.php"
 type:  annotation
```

**ContactusController**

```
<?php 

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;


class ContactusController extends Controller
{
/** 
* @Route("/contactus", name="_demo_contactus")
* @Template()
**/
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return array();
    }
}

?>
```

And then i have my view which is i am sure correct. Please provide the detailed answer so that it can help me in clearing my concepts as well. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the `SecuredController` from the `AcmeDemoBundle`, you'll see that the class declaration has this annotation at the start:

```
/**
 * @Route("/demo/secured")
 */
class SecuredController extends Controller
{
    // ...
```

This annotation prefixes all subsequent routes in the Controller class with `/demo/secured`. Therefore, you should write your own Controller using the same fashion:

```
/** 
 * @Route("/demo")
 */
class ContactusController extends Controller
{
    // ...
```

[See the docs concerning Route Prefixing for more information](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#route-prefix)

alternatively, you could also leave the `ContactusController` class alone and modify your route import instead:

```
_demo_contactus:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/ContactusController.php"
    type:  annotation
    prefix: /demo
```

You're also using the same route name twice, which means Symfony will reload routes and overwrite anything you had before for `_demo_contactus`. Try the following:

### routing.yml

```
_demo_contactus:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/ContactusController.php"
    type:  annotation
```

### ContactusController

```
<?php 

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

/** 
 * @Route("/demo/contactus")
 */
class ContactusController extends Controller
{
    /** 
    * @Route("/", name="_demo_contactus_home")
    * @Template()
    **/
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Make sure you try both `/demo/contactus` and `/demo/contactus/`.. it may be looking at that slash

Comment: I tried following both the ways but none resolve the issue. 

Currently i added 

/**
 * @Route("/demo/contactus")
 */

on the top of the ContactusController class but the url demo/contactus is not working.

Comment: @user3651267 So if you used `@Route("/demo/contactus")` on before the class declaration, you do realize that the route would then end up being `/demo/contactus/contactus` unless you change the `@Route` value before the `indexAction()` function to `@Route("/contactus", name="_demo_contactus")`? You should also make the route names different or else one will rewrite the other. I'm editing my answer appropriately.

Comment: @user3651267 No problem. If your problem has been resolved, please make sure you mark the answer that personally helped you the most by clicking the grey checkbox below the downvote/upvote buttons such that it turns green.